# how to send h.264 parameter sets 'out of band' during an ongoing RTP session?

Tags: h.264, rtp

I am implementing an RTSP server in my application to serve h264 video via RTP. I have read the relevant RFC's and spent a lot of time reading about h264/RTP/RTSP and one point which I am still confused about is how to transmit the 'Sequence Parameter Set' and 'Picture Parameter Set' out of band.

The documentation that I have read states that these should preferably be transmitted via a reliable out-of-band mechanism but I haven't been able to find anything that defines *how* to transmit them out of band other than using the sprop-parameter-sets attribute of an SDP file.

For instance, RFC 6184 Sectoin 8.4 states:

> Parameter set NALUs can be transported using three different
>     principles:
>
> A.  Using a session control protocol (out-of-band) prior to the
>         actual RTP session.
>
> B.  Using a session control protocol (out-of-band) during an ongoing
>         RTP session.
>
> C.  Within the RTP packet stream in the payload (in-band) during an
>         ongoing RTP session.

...

> It is recommended to implement principles A and B within a session
>      control protocol ...
>      Section 8.2.2 includes a detailed discussion on transport of
>      parameter sets in-band or out-of-band in SDP Offer/Answer using media
>      type parameters sprop-parameter-sets ... This
>      section contains guidelines on how principles A and B should be
>      implemented within session control protocols.

...

> Parameter sets MAY be added or updated during the lifetime of a
>      session using principles B and C.

I have read Sections 8.2.2 and 8.4 and cannot find any description of how to implement method 'B'. Everything that I have read on this topic is incredibly vauge, for instance, Wikipedia has the following to say on the subject:

> In other applications, it can be advantageous to convey the parameter sets "out-of-band" using a more reliable transport mechanism than the video channel itself.

What am I missing here? Is there some other standard for transmitting this via RTSP? RTCP?

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue ? I'm kinda stuck here too

Comment: No, there isn't a standard way of transmitting out-of-bound SPSes and PPSes. If you want to use option A or B you have to implement such a way yourself. For example you can use a simple TCP socket. Or you can put them in the SDP.